# How do I set an option to force-bypass confirmations in my bash script?

Tags: bash

I'm looking to add the option `--force` or `-f` to make it so that [Y/n] confirmation prompts don't appear.

I tried this:

```
if [[ $1 = "--name" ]] || [[ $1 = "-n" ]]; then
if [ -d "$2" ]; then # directory operand validity check
if [[ $3 == "--force" ]]; then
  read -r -p "'$2' will be sorted by file name. Continue? [Y/n] " response
fi
    if [[ $response =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]] || [[ $response == "" ]] || [[ $3 == "--force" ]]; then

             ... code ...

    elif [[ $response =~ ^([nN][oO]|[nN])$ ]]; then
      echo Aborting...
    else
      echo
      echo Invalid response \'$response\' -- Aborting...
    fi
else
  echo invalid directory operand \'$2\'
fi
```

but that still prompted the question.

Putting an if statement around the prompt and all of the outcomes wouldn't be ideal either, since I would have to copy the *Yes* outcome outside of it and that's too dodgy, even for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a simple script that shows how to make use of `getopts`. It parses options like `-f` and sets values accordingly.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

FORCED=0

# Parse options, now only -f and -m <val> is supported.
while getopts 'fm:' opt; do
        case $opt in
                f) FORCED=1;;
                m) FORCED=$OPTARG;;
                *) echo $opt not known;;
        esac
done

if [[ $FORCED -eq 0 ]]; then
        # Note that con can't be empty here.
        con="na"

        # Wait until y or n is given by user.
        until [[ "yn" =~ $con ]]; do
                read -p "Continue? (Y/n): " con

                # If con is empty, set it to 'y'.
                con=${con:-y}

                # Make content of con lowercase.
                con=${con,,}
        done
fi

# Do something with output.
if [[ $FORCED -eq 1 ]] || [[ $con == "y" ]]; then
        echo "Hello, world"
else
        echo "Aborted"
fi
exit 0
```

Try is yourself:

```sh
$ ./test.sh -f
Hello, world
$ ./test.sh -m 0
Continue? (Y/n): # I've only pressed enter here
Hello, world
$ ./test.sh -m 1
Hello, world
$ ./test.sh 
Continue? (Y/n): b
Continue? (Y/n): n
Aborted
```

Comment: Could you allow `$con` to be empty? I want to be able to answer y/"yes"/Enter or n/"no"

Comment: Hi, I wasn't clear in my comment. When setting `con`, it must have a value other than `n` or `y`, therefore I've set `con="na"`. It already works by pressing enter only due to `con=${con:-y}`.